# An Alternate proof of Nyquist-Shannon

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

This problem is from Basic Complex Analysis, Part 2A, by Barry Simon.

This problem will provide an alternate proof of the strong from of the Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem (Theorem 6.6.16 of Part 1), following closely the 1920 proof of Ogura. We'll suppose $f(z)$ is an entire function obeying

$|f(z)| \leq C \exp((\pi - \epsilon)| \Im z|)$

Fix $z_0 \in \mathbb{C} \backslash \mathbb{Z}$. Let

$g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{(z - z_0)\sin(\pi z)}$

and $R_k$ be the rectangle which is the boundary of $\{x + iy\ |\ |x| \le k + \frac{1}{2},\ |y| \le k + \frac{1}{2} \}$ oriented clockwise.

Prove that

$\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{R_k} |g(z)| d|z| = 0$

My attempt:

Choose $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ large enough such that $z_0$ is in the area bounded by $R_k$. Then let $z = x + iy$. Thus,
\begin{align*}
\int_{R_k} |g(z)| |dz| &\le \sup_{R_k}  \left | \frac{f(z)}{(z - z_0)(\sin(\pi z)} \right | \ell(R_k)\\
& \le  \sup_{R_k}  \left |  \frac{C \exp((\pi - \epsilon)| \Im z|)}{(\sin(\pi z))(k - |z_0|)} \right | 8(k + 1/2)\\
& = 8C  \sup_{R_k} \left| e^{-\epsilon |y|} \frac{e^{\pi|y|}}{\sin(\pi z)} \right | \frac{(k + 1/2)}{k - |z_0|}
\end{align*}

Then for $y > \frac{1}{2}$ we have,
\begin{align*}
\left | \frac{e^{\pi|y|}}{\sin(\pi z)} \right | = \left |\frac{2ie^{\pi y}}{e^{\pi i z} - e^{-\pi i z}} \right | \le \frac{2e^{\pi y}}{||e^{\pi i z}| - |e^{-\pi i z}||} = \frac{2e^{\pi y}}{e^{\pi y} - e^{-\pi y}} = \frac{2}{1 - e^{-2 \pi y}} \le \frac{2}{1 - e^{-\pi}}
\end{align*}
For $y < \frac{1}{2}$ we have,
\begin{align*}
\left | \frac{e^{\pi|y|}}{\sin(\pi z)} \right | = \left |\frac{2ie^{-\pi y}}{e^{\pi i z} - e^{-\pi i z}} \right | \le \frac{2e^{-\pi y}}{||e^{\pi i z}| - |e^{-\pi i z}||} = \frac{2e^{-\pi y}}{e^{-\pi y} - e^{\pi y}} = \frac{2}{1 - e^{2 \pi y}} \le \frac{2}{1 - e^{-\pi}}
\end{align*}
For $-\frac{1}{2} \le y \le \frac{1}{2}$ and $z = k + \frac{1}{2} + iy$ we have,

\begin{align*}
\left | \frac{e^{\pi|y|}}{\sin(\pi z)} \right | \le \frac{e^{\pi/2}}{|\sin( \pi(k + \frac{1}{2} + iy))|} = \frac{e^{\pi/2}}{|\sin( \frac{\pi}{2} + \pi iy))|} = \frac{e^{\pi/2}}{|\cosh(\pi y ))|} \le \frac{e^{\pi/2}}{|\cosh(\pi/2 ))|}
\end{align*}
Let $M = \max  \left \{  \frac{2}{1 - e^{-\pi}},  \frac{e^{\pi/2}}{|\cosh(\pi/2 ))|} \right \}$. 
Then $M$ does not depend on $k$, so
\begin{align*}
\int_{R_k} |g(z)| |dz| \le 8Ce^{-\epsilon |y|} M  \frac{(k + 1/2)}{k - |z_0|} 
\end{align*}
Which implies, for the top and bottom
\begin{align*}
\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{R_k} |g(z)| |dz| \le \lim_{k \to \infty} 8Ce^{-\epsilon |k+1|} M \frac{(k + 1/2)}{k - |z_0|}  = 0
\end{align*}
But what about the sides?

Comment: I'd say the $\frac{1}{z-z_0} = \mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{|z|})$ is there for making it $\to 0$ (and I got it : at the beginning it meant "$\pi$ minus \epsilon")

Comment: did you note that $\frac{f((k+1/2+iy)\pi)}{\sin((k+1/2+iy)\pi)}$ is bounded  by $e^{-\epsilon y}$ on $y \in (-k,k)$, and this independently of $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ ? hence the $\frac{1}{z-z_0}$ makes the integral  on the vertical sides $\to 0$

Comment: But then what cancels the k in the length of my contour?

Comment: Nevermind I get it. My contour doesn't depend on k there.

Comment: it does depend on $k$, but $\int_{-k}^k C e^{-\epsilon |y|} dy = \mathcal{O}(1)$ hence $\displaystyle\int_{-k}^k \frac{C e^{-\epsilon |y|} }{|k+iy-z_0|} dy \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$